# How to sum transactions amount from a table that is 2 degrees of relations away

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a stripped down version of my database structure

```
affiliates
    -id

users
    -id
    -affiliate_id

user_transactions
    -id
    -user_id
    -amount - integer
    -type - string(deposit, withdraw)
    -deposit_time - timestamp
```

What is the most performant way to get `affiliates` with summed up transactions by type (`deposit` or `withdraw` and some more) that happened yesterday?

So essentially what I need the SQL to return is

`affiliates.id, deposit_amount, withdraw_amount`

The way I'm doing now is with an ORM that basically executes 2 queries, 1 for affiliates and then something along these lines:

```
select id
(select sum(amount) from user_transactions as ut where ut.deposit_time = DATE(?) and ut.user_id = users.id and ut.type = deposit) as deposit_amount, 
(select sum(amount) from user_transactions as ut where ut.deposit_time = DATE(?) and ut.user_id = users.id and ut.type = withdraw) as withdraw_amount
from users where affiliate_id in ?
```

This is an approximate query. First 2 `?` are yesterday's date, the third is an array of user ids from the previous query.

What would be the most performant way to achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Will get some sample data. The desired result is `affiliates.id, deposit_amount, withdraw_amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `affiliates` table.  A simple `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, and some conditional aggregation suffice:

```
select u.affiliate_id,
       sum(case when type = 'deposit' then ut.amount else 0 end) as deposit,
       sum(case when type = 'withdraw' then ut.amount else 0 end) as withdraw
from users u join
     user_transactions ut
     on ut.user_id = u.id
group by u.affiliate_id;
```